# Initialize firebase app in react js shows error

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to initialize firebase app in my coreui admin panel react js.
I don't know how to initialize it. 
I have my credentials in `firebaseconfigure.js` .

And I imported it in login.js .

```
import 'firebase/auth';
import firebaseConfig from './firebaseConfig'

firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password).then((user) => {
alert(user);
```

But It not showing anything. why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the`firebase.initialize()`.

In your `login.js` file , add this following line after `import`.

```
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

Now check it again in login page. and let me know .